# А глаголы "писАть" и "пИсать" этимологически связаны между собой?

Tags: этимология

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое значение :

"пис**а**ть
Общеславянский глагол
индоевропейской природы,
восходящий к той же основе, что и
пестрый , с первоначальным
значением "делать пестрым,
украшать"." (Этим. словарь Крылова)

Художники пишут картины на холстах, народ пописывает каракули на бумаге. Схематичные рисунки называют пиктограммами. **Пикс**ели в дисплеях  имеют тот же смысл (элемент изображения).

Второе значение, также интернациональное, восходит, очевидно, к обычному звукоподражанию.

Comment: Собирался поспорить насчёт слова "пиксели". :-) Покопался в корнях -- похоже Вы правы. 

Pixel сокр. от pix element, где, в свою очередь, pix сокр. от picture (что много кто знает). А латинское слово pictura идёт от того же индоевропейского корня, что и русск. "писать" и "пестрый". +1 от меня. Интересно.

Comment: Спасибо автору интересного вопроса!

Answer (score 1):

Первое значение слова "писАть": 1.наносить на бумагу или иной материал графические знаки (буквы, цифры, ноты)
Второе слово - разговорное, просторечное. Его значение восходит,скорее всего,  к  звукоподражанию. Этот процесс имеет официальное толкование - "мочиться".

Answer (score 0):

Второе слово англицизм, от piss - мочиться, ссать